# How to bulk delete files in pages library in Sharepoint 2010 publishing site using UI/browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I want to bulk delete files in pages library in all the folders/sub folders using browser.

I don't want to delete using code.

Comment: Did you try to use  Site Content and Structure?

Answer (score 1):

Use **Site Content and Structure** to achieve it.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Work-with-site-content-and-structure-30fcaad9-02b1-4347-8b03-e1ccc5a4c19f

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Pages library, select files you want to delete
2. click delete on ribbon.

[image: delete items]

Are you having any issue in this?

Comment: pages lib has folders/sub folders, while deleting some folders, throwing error "checkout to other user, couldn't delete"